Using multiple PubSub in DAPR with Aspire
I have a .net 8 Aspire solution, in which i configure various micro services and attach a DAPR sidecar to each of them, like so:
// Aspire configuration

var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.AddDapr();

var resourcesPath = new List<string> { builder.Configuration["Dapr:ComponentsPath"]! }.ToImmutableHashSet();

var microServicesConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicroServices").Get<MicroServiceConfig[]>()!;
foreach (var config in microServicesConfig)
{
    if (!config.IsEnabled) continue;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(config.ProjectPath)) continue;

    builder.AddProject(config.ContainerName, config.ProjectPath!, "http")
        .WithDaprSidecar(new DaprSidecarOptions
            {
                AppId = config.ContainerName,
                Config = configFilePath,
                ResourcesPaths = resourcesPath,
                MetricsPort = config.MetricsPort,
                DaprHttpPort = config.DaprHttpPort,
                DaprGrpcPort = config.DaprGrpcPort,
                AppPort = config.AppPort,
            });
}

var app = builder.Build();

await app.RunAsync();

my appsettings.json looks like this:
{
  "Dapr": {
    "ComponentsPath": ".\\Dapr\\Components",
    "ConfigPath": ".\\Dapr\\config.yaml"
  }
  "MicroServices": [
  {
    "ContainerName": "user-api-service",
    "MetricsPort": 9092,
    "DaprHttpPort": 3502,
    "DaprGrpcPort": 50002,
    "AppPort": 7074,
    "HttpEndpoint": 5002,
    "ContainerPort": 8080,
    "ProjectPath": "../../user.apiService/user.apiService.csproj",
    "IsEnabled": true
  },
  {
    "ContainerName": "tenant-api-service",
    "MetricsPort": 9090,
    "DaprHttpPort": 3500,
    "DaprGrpcPort": 50000,
    "AppPort": 7238,
    "HttpEndpoint": 5004,
    "ContainerPort": 8080,
    "ProjectPath": "../../tenant.apiService/tenant.apiService.csproj",
    "IsEnabled": true
  },
  {
    "ContainerName": "sender-api-service",
    "MetricsPort": 9091,
    "DaprHttpPort": 3501,
    "DaprGrpcPort": 50001,
    "AppPort": 7070,
    "HttpEndpoint": 5001,
    "ContainerPort": 8080,
    "ProjectPath": "../../sender.apiService/sender.apiService.csproj",
    "IsEnabled": true
  }
}

This is my config.yaml:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: daprConfig
  namespace: default
spec:
  tracing:
    samplingRate: "1"
    zipkin:
      endpointAddress: http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans

This is the state store:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: StateStore
spec:
  type: state.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: ""
  - name: actorStateStore
    value: "true"


Last, these are the 2 pubsub components i want to use:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: UserPubSub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: ""

apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: TenantPubSub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: ""

As you can see, i have 3 projects: user, tenant and sender.
In the Aspire configuration, I am configuring all the pubsub components on all the micro services. I tried adding only the needed ones to each microservice: user only needs UserPubSub and the StateStore, same for tenant but with TenantPubSub instead of UserPubSub, and sender needs all 3 UserPubSub, TenantPubSub and the StateStore.
The result is always the same: I send a request expecting only user to receive it, but also tenant receives it.
The flow is this:

I call an api on sender
sender executes some logic and then returns the result to the client
The result from step 2 is also forwarded to user or tenant, based on which logic was executed - in this case only to user

I have an endpoint on sender to simulate the flow:
builder.MapGet
    ("send/{pubsub}/create/{message}", async (string pubsub, string message, [FromServices] DaprClient daprClient, CancellationToken ct) =>
    {
        await daprClient.PublishEventAsync(pubsub, "create", message, ct);
        return Results.Ok();
    });

The user micro service is subscribed to:
builder.MapPost
    ("user/create", [Topic("UserPubSub", "create")] async ([FromBody] string message) =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message)) return Results.Ok();
        return Results.BadRequest();
    });

While the tenant microservice is subscribed to:
builder.MapPost
    ("tenant/create", [Topic("TenantPubSub", "create")] async ([FromBody] string message) =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message)) return Results.Ok();
        return Results.BadRequest();
    });

I call the sender API with this request GET http://localhost:7238/send/UserPubSub/create/Hello, so i am expecting only the user micro service to receive the message.
Somehow, also the tenant microservice is receiving it.
What am i missing?
If you need more details, I'll be more than happy to enrich my question.

Has this solution worked outside of Aspire?, If not, or this is a new project, then I would say you need to use Dapr scopes https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/pubsub-scopes/.
